# Terraform KMS access denied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kms

I'm having a problem getting terraform to decyript my KMS cipertext.

I have used the aws cli to create a new KMS cipertext.

```
aws kms create-key
aws kms create-alias --alias-name alias/some-name --target-key-id KEYID
aws kms encrypt --key-id KEYID --plaintext SOMETEXT
```

In my terraform file I have added:

```
data "aws_kms_secrets" "example" {
  secret {
    name = "some-name"
    payload = "AQICAHgVf2E9PsbkjhirN4jL+dPBwssdKYuzvWfinKOjd/F3CAHsILNXf2iPu08U0FgT88FcAAAAfjB8BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagbzBtAgEAMGgGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMVxbKhOhe6Ykgqrc8AgEQgDv9fPIMcjvGOpK78J43xMMxR9C35cJvFT+JAHTxgd5Nk5lNfS+/AyJY+5W4TVq9sLw0Cz8ziSM/HW2xVg=="
  }
}
```

But, when I run `terraform plan` I get the following error:

```
data.aws_kms_secrets.example: Refreshing state...

Error: Failed to decrypt 'some-name': AccessDeniedException: The ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access.
status code: 400, request id: 8daef259-61b4-4cb0-9991-bb84ad76c71a
```

However, I can use the aws cli to successfuly decrypt the cipertext:

```
aws kms decrypt --profile=freid --region=eu-west-2 --ciphertext-blob fileb://<(echo AQICAHgVf2E9PsbkjhirN4jL+dPBwssdKYuzvWfinKOjd/F3CAHsILNXf2iPu08U0FgT88FcAAAAfjB8BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagbzBtAgEAMGgGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMVxbKhOhe6Ykgqrc8AgEQgDv9fPIMcjvGOpK78J43xMMxR9C35cJvFT+JAHTxgd5Nk5lNfS+/AyJY+5W4TVq9sLw0Cz8ziSM/HW2xVg== | base64 -D) --query Plaintext --output text | base64 -D
```

Both my cli and terraform use the same aws creds so I dont think it is a permissions issue.
I am using the region eu-west-2, but when I run `terraform plan` it asks me to set the `provider.aws.region` which I set to eu-west-2.
Im not sure why it asks me to set this because in the plan I set it anyway to eu-west-2:

```
provider aws {
  profile = "freid"
  region = "eu-west-2"
}
```

So, I am kind of confussed as to why terraform is getting an access denied excpetion.
Any help would be greatly appreachiated, you can find my tf files here: https://github.com/redstraw/sommelier/tree/master/infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise, but you need to add the provider into every .tf file when you are not using the default aws profile.

Once, I added this to `example.tf` it started working:

```
provider aws {
  profile = "freid" 
  region = "eu-west-2" 
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why this is the case. If anyone knows why please comment.

Comment: That's not true. All the .tf files in a folder get combined, you just need that in one of the files in the folder.

Comment: yeah, that is what I thought too. I originally just had this in my aws.tf file. But, after I added it into example.tf terraform was able to find the master key. When checking the logs I could see that when terraform tried to retrieve the master key it was using the default aws profile.

Comment: You should actually be getting an error that you have multiple `aws` providers without different aliases now. Since you aren't it appears your aws.tf file isn't being used? There's something wrong with your folder layout or something that is not apparent given the amount of detail you have provided in your question.